# Wireframe cube geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have just upgraded from `r59` to `r62` and noticed that the wireframe `CubeGeometry` has now rendered an extra diagonal line on each face. Is there a way to fix this?

```
volumeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(w, h, depth);
volumeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color : 0x0099ff,
      wireframe : true
    });
volumeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(volumeGeometry, volumeMaterial);
scene.add(volumeMesh);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all you want is a simple wireframe cube you can do this:

```
var cube = new THREE.BoxHelper();
cube.material.color.setRGB( 1, 0, 0 );
cube.scale.set( 10, 10, 10 );
scene.add( cube );
```

Comment: @Dan as additional explanation, you see the extra lines probably because Face4 (quads) were removed from Three.js, and CubeGeometry now uses two Face3 (triangles) for each side. BoxHelper uses line geometry I think, which is why it doesn't have that issue.

Comment: cube.scale.set( width/2, height/2, depth/2 );

Comment: Why is BoxHelper not in the documentation? Is it going to be deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

From the [shape example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_shapes):

```
var points = shape.createPointsGeometry();
var line = new THREE.Line( points, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
            color: 0xffffff
        }));
scene.add(line);
```